# processing.org on iOS, natively

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, processing, ogre3d, irrlicht

Since [processingjs](http://processingjs.org/) is terribly slow on the iPhone's webview with the animations I tested, I'm looking for an equivalent of http://wiki.processing.org/w/Android for iOS, that is, hardware acceleration via OpenGL -- maybe a game library like cocos2d-x but I couldn't find one that understands Processing.org scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend having a look at [Davide Della Casa's P5Nitro](https://github.com/davidedc/P5Nitro) project. I've seen a spring based sample running on both P5 Nitro and iProcessing and the P5Nitro version was much smoother.

Also, I think you should try [OpenFrameworks](http://www.openframeworks.cc/download/), a c++ project inspired by Processing (loads of familiar functions already supported) which can also target iOS.

In conclusion, try P5Nitro and see if it does the job for you out of the box, if not, have a look at openFrameworks and try to port/chance your Processing code a bit. There's a nice little [guide for Processing users](http://www.openframeworks.cc/tutorials/firstSteps/002_openFrameworks_for_processing_users.html) available.

Comment: "P5Nitro is in its infancy" says the site and development stopped more than a year ago, but it seems like a good attempt for a wrapper around hxOpenFrameworks. So any case OpenFrameworks is the way to go (or Cinder, depends on your taste). Thanks, answer accepted!

Answer (score 1):

I got a decent performance of processingjs in the iphone using http://procoding.audiocommander.de have you tried it? I also found this 
http://www.luckybite.com/iprocessing/
, but is is not well documented and seems to be not updated in a long time, so i did not tried.

Comment: They both are based on processingjs. I realize that it does support OpenGL via WebGL which can be enabled on iPhone via the private api trick (https://github.com/atnan/UIWebViewWebGL) but I'm still getting terrible speed when compared to running it in normal desktop mode. Try with this one: http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/700

Comment: thanks @jesses-co-tt, they seem to have a proof-of-concept video only, see http://seditious-tech.com/2011/06/06/product-announcement-processing-for-ios, their shipped product "is running on the old Mobile Safari JS engine" (quote from the above link)